# Multiple blank lines with spaces, tabs and new lines to one line?

Tags: php

I know there are similar questions, but i have certain different problems!

I need to convert multiple blank lines to one in PHP, but when I use not only New Lines, but Spaces and New Lines it doesn't work. If there are 2 or more blank lines(with spaces and enter's), they should be converted in only one blank line, when it's only new line(but not
 blank line), it should remain the same.

I used this, but it doesn't work with spaces and new lines:

```
$string = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "<br />", $string);

echo preg_replace("~<br />(<br\s*/?>[\r\n]*)+~i", "<br /><br />", $string);
```

I also need it to be displayed in this way in Windows, Linux and Mac!

Comment: What is this question in regards to? What programming language?

Comment: You could simply say I want to remove blank lines from text

Answer (score 1):

I think these are the only things you need

```
$str = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), ' ', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/(\s+)/', ' ', $str);
```

Comment: My problem is that I need to convert it to <br />, and then if there is <br /> it remains the same, but if there are two or more to be converted to only two.

Comment: Only returns? Try with `$str = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '<br />', $str);`

Answer (score 0):

Try [following](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/c51be.php)

```
<?php 
$str = ' 



aa 
a 


a 

a 
'; 

for($i = 1;$i< 8;$i++){ 
    $str = str_replace("\r\n\r\n\r\n", "\r\n\r\n", $str); 
    $str = str_replace("\t", '', $str); 
} 

echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $string);
```

Comment: regex on such an easy string?